# Dropdown não funciona

Tags: html, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um menu Dropdown que apresenta os links para a galeria e para os videos, no entanto, se estiver numa outra view além da index.ctp o dropdown já não funciona. Mas se eu pegar no `dropdown.js` da distribuição "source code" e a incluir no layout, não funcionam os dropdowns no `index.ctp` mas nas outras páginas já funciona. Ao pesquisar no google descubri um [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bootstrap-stackoverflow/D6CAiwOZI8w) que fez com que os dropdowns funcionassem, no entanto apenas abriam uma vez na view `index.ctp`. qual é o problema?

Estou a utilizar o twitter bootstrap(a versão mais compacta) e o CakePHP 2.4.4

**Layout**

```
      <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Música', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Musica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Animação Temática', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'AnimacaoTematica'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Promoção', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Promocao'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Staff', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Staff'))?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Aluguer', array('controller'=>'services', 'action'=>'Aluguer'))?></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

**Head do Layout**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');

    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->element('fancybox_links');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0');
    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->element('fancybox_links');
    echo $this->Html->css('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5');
    echo $this->Html->script('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5');        
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox3").fancybox(e){
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'float'
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            });
    </script> 
    <!--<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
```

[Erros da view cartaz.ctp](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/cartaz_zps51fb0b8f.png).

[Erros da view index.ctp](http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h184/SunTzu1988/index_zps58d860ab.png).

Comment: Como assim não funciona?

Comment: O seu `li.dropdown` está dentro de um `ul` certo?

Comment: Sim está, ele funciona apenas se eu estiver na view `index.ctp`, noutras páginas fica vazio, o link fica com o `#` mas o dropdown não abre.

Comment: Se ele só funciona em uma pagina, você tem certeza que nas outras está chamando o css e javascript corretamente?

Comment: Sim, elas usam todas o mesmo layout. Eu vou fazer um update à questão com os erros que aparecem na consola do chrome.

Comment: Estou agora a ver que os ficheiros com o erro 404 têm versão anterior ao fancybox no link do seu comentário e do plugin que estou a usar. Existe alguma forma de, através da consola, saber o que está a requerer esses ficheiros exactamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após ter feito uma limpeza de ficheiros .js na pasta webroot, e ter reisntalado o fancybox,  [deste](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions) link, e depois [este](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin/tree/master/Fancybox) plugin, os dropdowns começaram a funcionar correctamente.

**Head do Layout**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');

    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');

    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    echo $this->Html->script('collapse');
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox3").fancybox(e){
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'float'
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            });
    </script> -->
    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como não tenho permissão para comentar estou a responder. Pelo que vejo dos erros os *scripts* que usas não estão a ser carregados. Começa a tentar resolver os erros de cima para baixo.

Primeiro porque é que o *jQuery* não está a ser carregado.
Depois vejo ai alguns acessos não permitidos, tens de garantir que os teus *scripts* estão acessíveis.

**Inspeciona a página de cada um `cartaz.ctp` e `index.ctp` e experimenta o link de cada um dos *scripts* no *browser* a ver se aparece alguma coisa, se não existe ou acesso negado.**

Comment: Estes erros do fancybox são bastante estranhos,pois ele está a pedir ficheiros que nem sequer existem no [plugin](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin) fancybox para o CakePHP que estou a utilizar, e acabando de o reinstalar continuo com o mesmo conjunto de erros.

Comment: Podem ser ficheiros externos. Já viste [isto](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions)?

Comment: Os ficheiros no Link que colocou são mais recentes, têm versões diferentes. Eu creio que não instalei correctamente o meu [plugin](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin/tree/master/Fancybox), seria possivel dar-me uma ajuda nisso? Não estou a compreender muito bem os passos 2 e 4, nem onde colocar o conteudo do [zip](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license).

Comment: Vê [isto](http://deliciouscakephp.com/cakephp-fancybox-plugin/). Pelo que percebi tens de descompactar o zip e por **o conteúdo** em 'app/Plugin'

Comment: Pois foi o que fiz. Vi também que os ficheiro que estão em falta são ficheiros pertencentes ao Fancybox 1, no entanto nas instruções, o link leva ao Fancybox 2, e que também alguns dos ficheiros que estão em falta estão incluídos no na layout e os ficheiros existem na pasta webroot.